# Editing the View Properties in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, properties, sharepoint-2010, metadata

Hi i am very new to sharepoint and have been asked to modify the page that is shown when you "view properties" on a document.
By default all the document properties are shown in a long list which is not ideal when there are a lot of properties. Ideally we would like to see a tabbed layout that groups the metadata.
I have done some searching but have come up with nothing, i dont even know if this is possible or if there is a different way to tackle this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry! Please improve your question. Not able to understand clearly.

Comment: I have edited the question due to some typos i saw which may have made it unclear. Basically there is a page that is shown when you "View Properties" of a document. This page has links to version history, manage permissions, delete etc along with all the properties or metadata associated with the document. I would like to know if it is possible to edit this page, preferably in a way to group different types of metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think it is a page. According to my understanding you want to edit the context menu of an item. Please confirm

Comment: It's what comes up when you "View Properties" of a document, it contains information such as Title, Edited By, Edited At, etc. Is it even possible to edit the layout of this?

Comment: Are you referring to displayform.aspx..??
The following link might help you if you are looking for the same.
http://davidandrewsmith.us/2009/09/11/how-to-edit-dispform-aspx/

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i need, ill tackle it tomorrow and update. Thanks